# AJAX form autofill suggestion

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I am trying to create an html form that uses AJAX to load database entries from a mysql database as the user types, so it suggests them to the user.

I am new to AJAX and I am kind of stuck with something that probably is quite simple for more experienced people.

I have this html text input:

```
<form>
    <input  type="text" id="f" />
</form>
```

This jQuery script:

```
$(function(){
ajaxTest();
})

function ajaxTest(){
$('#f').keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getit.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'data' : this.value},
        success: function(response){
            for(var i = 0; i < (response.rows*2); i = i+2){
            alert('The name is ' + response[i] + ' ' + response[i+1])
            }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

And this php script:

```
//connect to database
//get variables an sanitize
$parameter = $_GET['data'];
$parameter = mysql_real_escape_string( $parameter );

//prepare and run query
$query = "SELECT email , surname , address FROM users WHERE email LIKE '$parameter%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

//start preparing response
$seires = mysql_num_rows($result);
$response = array('rows'=>$seires);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    array_push( &$response , $row['onoma'] , $row['epwnimo'] );
    }
echo json_encode($response);
```

This gets my job done, but I am wondering:

1) Am I using any bad practices?

2) Is there a smarter way to pass the data from the php script to the jQuery script?

3) In html, what tag could I use to display the suggestions to the user? A p with an onclick function to fill the form perhaps or is there something better?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery UI Autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Oh, and to answer your questions:  1) Not really, if I were implementing an autocomplete from scratch I would do basically the same thing.  2)  Again, building it from scratch, the method you are using seems pretty straight-forward.  3)  Since you're returning a list of suggestions, an unordered list of <li> tags would be appropriate.  But if you re-invent the wheel (there are already some good implementations out there), you'll have to figure out how to style the list and display it in an appropriate spot, and respond to selection events.

Comment: It's not really about re-invention. I just want to practice since I have no idea on AJAX. I posted the question because my code does not seem to be so maintainable - what if a client asks me to show one more row per result? I would have to change the value everywhere. Or what if I wanted a jQuery script to use the same php file to display only the name and no other information? wouldn't there be a smarter to pass data from php to jquery? Might be just me, but my code seems to be a bit 'messy'..

Comment: Sure, I totally understand.  "Reinventing" is a good learning exercise.  For production quality code, you are better off with something that has been consumed by the masses, but learning is a different matter.  I'll usually restrict my server script results to a reasonable default to display, like 10 rows.  But allow the user to provide an optional parameter to override the default.  You may also want a "minLength" parameter in your jQuery script... might not make sense in some scenarios to make the ajax call on the first keystroke.  So yeah, there are ways to refine it.

Comment: @AnPel if you practicing, try wrapping the code in a jQuery plugin (like the autocomplete).  It is a good way to brush up on keeping code reuseable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be worried about making too many ajax calls.  It is likely that someone will be typing  fast. So if I type 'abc' then you will make 3 ajax calls.  Lots of overhead.  However, if you to implement a delay before sending like 300 milliseconds then the script will wait for a pause before returning results.

I find that a short (really unnoticeable) delay is better than a flicker in the suggestions.

Also, you might consider posting this on codereview (stackoverflow's companion site). It is better suited for answer questions like this one.

Here is an untested example of what I am referring to:

```
$(function(){
    var timer;

    var getSuggestions = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getit.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'data' : $('#f').value},
            success: function(response){
                for(var i = 0; i < (response.rows*2); i = i+2){
                    alert('The name is ' + response[i] + ' ' + response[i+1])
                }
            }
        })
    });

    $('#f').keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(getSuggestions, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: good contribution. +1. I don't really like the for loop in my jQuery script, because if in the future I need to display say the person's age, I will have to change everything. Is there a way to pass the whole $row array to jQuery and decide what to do with it there?

Comment: checkout jQuery's each method or look to underscore if you don't want to use pure javascript.  If it is the look that you don't like--I agree.  I usually name my callback in a variable like insertData and just pass then into the ajax call.  It helps with readability down the line. Also, a for.. in or forEach loop might be better alternative for you.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) implementation, you can use the whole html/css/js package or "steal" the html only, or just read the code for some inspiration..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead, be sure to take a look at this 
https://gist.github.com/1848558 (linked from https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1997)

Basically it binds a keyup event to the typeahead field, which in turn makes an AJAX call, dynamically populating the typeahead source.  This is all done without having modify the Typeahead core.

There is also a Twitter Bootstrap "Combobox" floating around.  I won't link to it since I ended up going with the solution in the gist, but you can search for it yourself if you like.